# Ansible - Unable to ping windows VM

Tags: ansible

I created an Azure Windows 2019 server and ran the ConfiguringRemotingForAnsible.ps1. When I try to ping the server getting the error

```
<13.82.47.35> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: *** on PORT 5986 TO **.**.**.**
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
[WARNING]: ERROR DURING WINRM SEND INPUT - attempting to recover: WinRMError The pipe is being closed.  (extended fault data: {'transport_message': 'Bad HTTP response
returned from server. Code 500', 'http_status_code': 500, 'wsmanfault_code': '232', 'fault_code': 's:Receiver', 'fault_subcode': 'w:InternalError'})
13.82.47.35 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm send_input failed; \nstdout: \nstderr S\u0000t\u0000a\u0000r\u0000t\u0000i\u0000n\u0000g\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000C\u0000L\u0000R\u0000 \u0000f\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000e\u0000d\u0000 \u0000w\u0000i\u0000t\u0000h\u0000 \u0000H\u0000R\u0000E\u0000S\u0000U\u0000L\u0000T\u0000 \u00008\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00004\u00000\u00000\u00005\u0000.\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000"
}
```

Command used - ansible -i hosts win -m win_ping

hosts

```
[win]
x.x.x.x

[win:vars]
ansible_password=*************
ansible_connection=winrm 
ansible_winrm_transport=basic 
ansible_shell_type=powershell 
ansible_user=*****
ansible_port=5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error output states "Starting the CLR failed with HRESULT 80004005" - this error typically points to a .NET framework install which needs to be repaired or reinstalled. Try reinstalling .net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx

I was able to successfully test your inventory file setup above on a cleanly built Windows 2019 instance, so I believe your config is sound.

Comment: Thank you. Installing the .net resolved the issue.